# what's causing this Entity Framework 6 runtime error - type or namespace does not exist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

This is an ASP.NET (Framework v. 4.5.2) website currently running reliably in production. A new requirement called for adding a new column to an existing SQL Server table (apProduct) which has been done. I then made the necessary changes to the .edmx file, controllers, views, etc., and everything is compiling fine. However I'm now getting the runtime error below:

[image]

When I debug and set a breakpoint where apDepartment is first getting created, I expand the created objects and see this:

[image]

My attention is drawn to: "The metadata for 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-AnkoMVC' is invalid."

Here is where apProduct is defined, clearly within the AnkoMVC.Models namespace:

[image]

Lastly, here is the DbContext class:

[image]

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to overcome this?

Comment: Can you show your index view? I can't check if you miss namespace there?

Comment: Where is the class definition for apDepartment?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in the @model reference in many of the views. Here is the faulty code:

[image]

This is the corrected @model reference:

[image]

Thanks!